# how to change wave movement from horizontal to vertical with wave-component?

Tags: javascript, aframe

Currently the wave-component generates an horizontal move. My interest is to change that movement from horizontal to a vertical movement. The current script is:

```
<script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('wave-component', {
            schema: {
                texturepath: {type: 'asset'},
                color: {type: 'string', default: '#FFF'}
            },
            init: function () {
                var el = this.el;
                const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 3, 60, 100);

                // Creating a material with the texture path provided
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: loader.load(this.data.texturepath.src),
                    transparent: true,
                    color: this.data.color,
                    alphaTest: 0.01
                });
                var wave = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                wave.rotation.set(-0.3, 0.0, -0.0);
                const clock = new THREE.Clock();
                let v = new THREE.Vector3();
                let pos = wave.geometry.attributes.position;
                el.setObject3D('WaveMesh', wave);
                // Function to animate each vertex of the texture to simulate a wave effect
                function animate() {
                    const t = clock.getElapsedTime();
                    for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
                        v.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
                        const wavex1 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3);
                        const wavex2 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 5 + t * 2);
                        const wavex3 = 0.1 * Math.sin(v.y * 10 + t * 0.5);
                        pos.setZ(i, wavex1 + wavex2 + wavex3)
                    }
                    pos.needsUpdate = true;
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                }
                animate();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I am looking for a vertical movement instead of horizontal movement.

Comment: At a guess -> setZ changes to setY.  If you can provide a runnable snippet that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You combine three sine factors into the final position:

```
const wavex1 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3);             
const wavex2 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 5 + t * 2);
const wavex3 = 0.1 * Math.sin(v.y * 10 + t * 0.5);
```

If you want the waves to move equally fast in two dimensions, then just speed up the factor depending on the `v.y` position (since its 4 times slower than the rest):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('wave-component', {
    schema: {
      color: {
        type: 'string',
        default: '#FAA'
      }
    },
    init: function() {
      var el = this.el;
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(6, 6, 100, 100);

      // Creating a material with the texture path provided
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: this.data.color,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
      });
      var wave = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      wave.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, 0.0, -0.0);
      const clock = new THREE.Clock();
      let v = new THREE.Vector3();
      let pos = wave.geometry.attributes.position;
      el.setObject3D('WaveMesh', wave);
      // Function to animate each vertex of the texture to simulate a wave effect
      function animate() {
        const t = clock.getElapsedTime();
        for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
          v.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
          const wavex1 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3);
          const wavex2 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 5 + t * 2);
          const wavex3 = 0.1 * Math.sin(v.y * 5 + t * 3);
          pos.setZ(i, wavex1 + wavex2 + wavex3)
         
        }
        pos.needsUpdate = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      animate();
    }
  });

</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 1 -6" rotation="0 45 0 " wave-component></a-entity>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

If you want it to wave in another direction, swap the factors or just rotate the plane.